# Javascript keyup function throwing wrong alert message

Tags: javascript, html, keyup

With the following script, i am trying to validate whether the refund amount `wlt_ln_refund_amt` is greater than the balance amount `wlt_ln_bal` using keyup function.

- In my html read only field `wlt_ln_bal` (field type = number) i have a an amount 222.00
- the other field `wlt_ln_refund_amt` (field type = number)

The testcase

- for the value 3 the system is throwing an error message like "Refund amount Rs.3 is greater than Balance Rs.222.
- for the values 1, 2 or 2000 the system is not throwing any errors

Here is my html code:

```
<form id="lnrefund" name="lnrefund" 
    method="post" role="form" 
    class="form-horizontal" 
    action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" 
    onsubmit="return (checkform() && confirm_update())">    
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 control-label">Loan Balance</label>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">       
       <input id="wlt_ln_bal" Name="wlt_ln_bal" 
        type="number"value ="<?php echo $bal ?>" 
        class="form-control required" readonly/>
       <span class="help-block">Required</span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 control-label">Refund Amount</label>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <input id="wlt_ln_refund_amt" 
           Name="wlt_ln_refund_amt"type="number" step="0.01" 
           class="form-control" required/>
    <span class="help-block">Required</span>
   </div>
</form>
```

And this is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#wlt_ln_refund_amt").keyup(function () {
var ref = document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_refund_amt.value;
var bal = document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_bal.value;
if (ref>bal)
    { 
     alert('Refund amount Rs.'+ref+  '\nis greater than Available Balance Rs.'+bal)
          return true;
          }
      });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Is `document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_refund_amt.value` a valid selector?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the variables are  being compared as strings (i.e. alphabetically) you should try something like

```
        var ref = parseInt(document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_refund_amt.value);
        var bal = parseInt(document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_bal.value);
```

or maybe

```
        var ref = parseFloat(document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_refund_amt.value);
        var bal = parseFloat(document.lnrefund.wlt_ln_bal.value);
```

if you're expectiong decimals

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Both the above solutions are working as expected. thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for suggestions... :P

I'd use jQuery to get the values of the two inputs. You're already using jQuery for the document ready function, so why not use:

```
var $refund = $('#wlt_ln_refund_amt'),
    $balance = $('#wlt_ln_bal.value');
```

What you're doing works fine - as long as the structure of your HTML never changes. Using jQuery like this means you don't have to worry about ever wrapping your inputs in a containing DIV or changing the form to a popup dialog later on.

Next, I wouldn't use the keyup event, I'd use the blur event. Perhaps your use case requires the check after every keystroke, but that usually annoys users. If you bind to the blur instead of the keyup, your user will have an opportunity to correct a mistake during typing before getting yelled at by your function.

```
$refund.on('blur', function(){
    var refAmount = parseInt($refund.val()),
        balAmount = $balance.val() * 1;
        if (refAmount > balAmount)
        { 
            alert('Refund amount Rs.' +
                  refAmount +  
                  '\nis greater than Available Balance Rs.' +
                  balAmount);
            $refund.focus();
        }
});
```

As someone else suggested, make sure the values you're comparing are numeric. You can use the parseInt as suggested (the preferred way) or force type conversion by multiplying the value by 1. Either way will result in a NaN (not a number) if the user enters something other than numbers.

After the alert, I'd return focus back to the refund amount to give the user another shot at the entry.

As a final suggestion, I'd recommend using readable variable names. Perhaps you shortened them just for this question, but descriptive variable names are much easier to deal with than obscure abbreviations.

Good luck!